# Combine parallel and sequential commands

Tags: shell, parallelism, gnu-parallel

### 1. Summary

I don't understand, how I can combine parallel and sequential commands in Linux.

---

### 2. Expected behavior

*Pseudocode*:

`pip install pipenv` **sequential** `pipenv install --dev`

**parallel** task

`npm install -g grunt-cli` **sequential** `npm install`

*Windows batch working equivalent*:

```bat
start cmd /C "pip install pipenv & pipenv install --dev"
start cmd /C "npm install -g grunt-cli & npm install"
```

---

### 3. Not helped

1. I don't think, that [**`&` and `wait`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19543185/5951529) can solve this problem, see [**rsaw comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543139/19543185#comment38550478_19543185).
2. I read, that [**GNU parallel — is better way for parallel tasks**](https://www.codeword.xyz/2015/09/02/three-ways-to-script-processes-in-parallel/), but I can't find, which syntax I need to use in [**GNU parallel**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19543286/5951529), that solve this task.
3. I try [**parallelshell**](https://github.com/darkguy2008/parallelshell):

   ```shell
   parallelshell "pip install pipenv && pipenv install --dev" "npm install -g grunt-cli && npm install"
   ```

   Full `.sh` file:

   ```shell
   git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/Kristinita/KristinitaPelican
   wait
   cd KristinitaPelican
   wait
   parallelshell "pip install pipenv && pipenv install --dev" "npm install -g grunt-cli && npm install"
   ```

   But at first `pipenv install --dev` command run for me, then `npm install`. It sequential, not parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply with GNU **`parallel`**:

```
parallel ::: 'pip install pipenv && pipenv install --dev' \
             'npm install -g grunt-cli && npm install'
```

Comment: [**Thanks!**](https://travis-ci.org/Kristinita/SashaPelicanTest/jobs/347686349#L486)

Comment: @СашаЧерных, you're welcome

Answer (score 2):

The Unix-style equivalent of your Windows commands is the following:

```
(pip install pipenv && pipenv install --dev) >& pip.log &
(npm install -g grunt-cli && npm install) >& npm.log &
```

This starts two sub-shells in the background, one running `pip` followed by `pipenv` (if `pip` completes without error), the other running the two `npm` commands. Both sets of commands’ outputs are redirected to log files, to keep things intelligible.

If you need to wait for all those commands to complete before continuing, use

```
wait
```

as you’ve discovered already.

When sequencing and parallelising tasks using a POSIX-style shell, there are two tools at your disposal:

- job control, which allows you to place tasks in the background (using `&` at the end of a command), and allows you to wait for their completion (using `wait`)
- sub-shells, which allow you to split units of processing up in whatever way you like, including serialising tasks which need to be handled sequentially.

That’s good enough for simple requirements such as your current task, and can get you quite a long way. More advanced tools exist for more complex use-cases; GNU Parallel is one, it’s also worth looking into batching tools if you need finer resource control.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I still have a problems. // **1.** If I run your script in Windows use Cygwin, pipenv doesn't install for me, see [**`pip.log` traceback**](https://www.pastery.net/jspsvw/). If I run commands sequential or I use Windows parallel tasks from my batch script above, all success. (I get same traceback, when I try [**npm parallel**](https://github.com/flesler/parallel)).

Comment: // **2.** Travis CI [**skip your script**](https://travis-ci.org/Kristinita/SashaPelicanTest/jobs/347664739#L458). If I use commands [**sequential**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaPelicanTest/blob/94de75e3dde844e3d2edaa91fd8afeadd7cd7382/travis.sh), [**build passed**](https://travis-ci.org/Kristinita/SashaPelicanTest/jobs/347675395#L458). // Thanks.

Comment: Weird, I would expect that to work on Travis CI... Never mind, since `parallel` works for you!